# iOS 13: How to detect "Voice Control" is running

Tags: ios, swift, voice-control

Is there an API similar to `UIAccessibility.isVoiceOverRunning` to detect whether or not Voice Control is running in iOS 13?  I am unable to find anything for this in the current [beta docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibility?changes=latest_minor).

Voice Control: https://www.apple.com/ios/ios-13-preview/features/ (see Accessibility section).

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is highlighted about this amazing new feature but its **['accessibilityUserInputLabels'](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/3197989-accessibilityuserinputlabels?language=objc)** property: neither [event name](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/criteria-ios.html#accessibility-options) nor [notification](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/en/mobile/ios/development/#accessibility-options) unfortunately.

Wait for the official release of iOS 13 that may provide some news in the final documentation: light a candle as I do.  ;o)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround when you need to show different UI when the user is in Voice Control.

Since there is no API like `UIAccessibility.isVoiceOverRunning` for Voice Control you'll need to override `accessibilityActivate` to know when the user is interacting with your app using an accessibility feature.

```swift
class Button: UIButton {

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleTouchUpInside), for: .touchUpInside)
  }

  override func accessibilityActivate() -> Bool {
    // Launch more accessible UI
    if UIAccessibility.isVoiceOverRunning {
      // VoiceOver
    } else if UIAccessibility.isSwitchControlRunning {
      // Switch Control
    } else {
      // Probably used Voice Control or Full Keyboard Access
    }
    return true
  }

  @objc func handleTouchUpInside() {
    // Standard interaction - continue to show default UI
  }
}
```

Comment: using 'accessibilityActivate()' is great but I don't understand how you can detect that the VoiceControl feature is running and not something else?

Comment: @XLE_22 I added a check to detect if it's most likely Voice control or Full Keyboard Access.  Again, since there is no API to support this yet it's just a best guess.

Comment: @XLE_22 I have checked your above code. This is not working.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
observe(UIAccessibility.voiceOverStatusDidChangeNotification, selector: #selector(voiceOverStatusDidChange))

@objc private func voiceOverStatusDidChange() {
    if UIAccessibility.isVoiceOverRunning {
      // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Prabhakar, the question is for Voice Control not Voice Over

Comment: Oops, sorry I missed that part!